# onecolumn titlepage, twocolumn rest of document

Tags: titles, two-column

I recently switched from using `multicol`s to `twocolumn` in the documentclass since `multicol`s tends to mess with my graphics. However, this also means that my title page is now also two colums, which I'd like to change.

Keep in mind that I'd still like to keep my abstract on the same page as the title. I use `\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}}` to create a horizontal line after my titel. Everything after that should be two column.

Comment: Would the abstract also be one-column?

Comment: No, everything beyond the horizontal line that ends the titelpage (titel, author etc) should be twocolum, starting with the abstract.

Comment: So, if I understand well, on the title page, only the title itself should be in one column?

Comment: Also, which document class do you use?

Comment: yes, just the title, but no new page before switching to twocolumns. I use an article

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this be what you want? It uses the `strip` environment, from `cuted`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, twoside]{article}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{A nice title}
\author{Ye author}
\date{\today}
\setlength\columnsep{3em}

\begin{document}

\begin{strip}
  \vspace*{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\stripsep\relax}
  \centering
  \maketitle
  \vskip\baselineskip
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\rule{1.1\paperwidth}{0.4pt}}
  \vskip\baselineskip
\end{strip}

  \begin{abstract}
      This is a test for an abstract in two column mode. This is a test for an abstract in two column mode. This is a test for an abstract in two column mode. This is a test for an abstract in two column mode. This is a test for an abstract in two column mode.
  \end{abstract}
\section{A nice section}
    \lipsum[1-2]
\section{A nicer section}
    \lipsum[3-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, looks good. Got some other issues now that arose but I'll make another thread tonight when I got time to deal with it.

Comment: As a follow up question: If i wanted to add some more Information to the title, say below the date, for example my university, where exactly should i put the text?

Comment: You should use the `titlingpage` environment (from the `titling` package) inside `strip`. The titling package defines 4 hooks and you can use the fourth hook (`\titlehookd`) to add code after the date. Cf. § 2.1 of the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities:

1. twocolumn

\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text

```
\begin{document}
\title{}
\author{}
\twocolumn[
\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum
\end{abstract}
\end{@twocolumnfalse}
]
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Here, your title and your abstract will be onecolumn format and everything after is twocolumn layout. If you want the abstract also in twocolumn format, you have to set it after the `\end{@twocolumnfalse}.

2. multicol

Just type it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text

\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[2]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```